# Synchronization and Ordering in distributed systems. Eg: File consistency on concurrent writes in a distributed file storage service like Dropbox

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, backend, consistency, system-design

I've been trying to understand the system design for a service like Dropbox. I went through the 'Grokking the System Design' solution for this. But I don't understand how DropBox ensures consistency of a file that is being modified concurrently from two different devices.

Consider the case:

```
Client1: File1:{C1,C2,C3,C4}
Client2: File1:{C1,C2,C3,C4}
Server Metadata: File1:{C1,C2,C3,C4}
```

Client1 modifies C1, C2 chunks. Client2 modified C1,C2,C3,C4 chunks. This happens at the same time on both clients.

```
Client1: File1:{C1',C2',C3,C4}
Client2: File1:{C1'',C2'',C3'',C4''}
Server Metadata: File1:{C1',C2',C3'',C4''}
```

In the above example we see that the file on the server appears as a mashup of the two files.
How does the system ensure that the file on the server is either {C1',C2',C3,C4} or {C1'',C2'',C3'',C4''}

And in general how do distributed systems handle concurrent updates to the same resource? How are synchronization, ordering and locking ensured?

Comment: Not an answer your question directly, but in general I find articles on distributed database design to be quite useful when looking at general concepts. You might find [these](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41344.pdf) [three](https://jepsen.io/consistency) unaffiliated posts to provide some [useful knowledge](https://aphyr.com/posts/313-strong-consistency-models)

Comment: Even on a regular filesystem, running on a single Linux machine, with a single user, running 2 separate programs that modify the same file, this scenario can happen. On the other hand, S3 avoids this by making every upload a complete swap of the old file.